# Simple ConsoleProgram with IDisposable - No memory decrease - we have a leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, idisposable

I have got a simple ConsoleProgram which is creating a list of 80 IDisposable objects. This object hold two `System.Threading.ManualResetEvent` which are closed in the `Dispose()` method. Please consider the code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        Test(80);
        Console.WriteLine("end.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Test(int c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test start.");

        List<TestObject> list = new List<TestObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            list.Add(new TestObject());

        Console.WriteLine("End of adding. Added: {0} items.", c);
        Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (TestObject obj in list)
            obj.Dispose();

        list = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose end.");
    }

    public class TestObject : IDisposable
    {
        public ManualResetEvent mr1 = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        public ManualResetEvent mr2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            mr1.Close();
            mr2.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested my program in case of consumed memory and memory leaks. I supposed that consumed memory will increase after creating all list objects, but it will decrease after calling the `Dispose()` method and setting `null` value to the list object. Unfortunately I have observer different behaviour. Please consider following result of my test:

1. Program starts (nothing created). WorkingSet = 6.700K
2. List of 80 objects was created. WorkingSet = 7.160K (memory grow: 460K)
3. Program called the `Dispose()` method an set `null` to list object. WorkingSet = 7.164K (memory grow form last point: 4K)
4. Program is hanging for more than 20 minutes. WorkingSet = 7.296K (memory grow from last point: 105K, memory grow from the beginning: 596K)
5. Program was closed.

I am really confused about the point 3 and 4. Why the memory was not released? I think that this is a memory leak, because the total memory grow was equal to 596K and it was never released.

Thank you very much for any answer.

PS. Changing the number of object, for example to 9000, cause a memory growth of more than 2MB.

PS2. At the end of my program I am calling `GC.Collect()` to force the clean-up. But after that amount of used memory is still the same and it is not decreasing - I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `Dispose()` and setting a value to null does *not* free the memory up immediately.  Your memory should be released when the Garbage Collector next runs, but this time is not deterministic. Typically, it will happen when the application is under memory pressure, usually as a result of object creation requesting more memory.  Without that pressure, and with the application idle, the GC might never collect your memory.

In short, this is not a memory leak.

Comment: So GC will collect the memory only under memory pressure? I thought that leaving program for more than 20 minutes will make that GC will do the work.

Comment: Not necessarily; the GC is non-deterministic.  Also, I would point out that even the 2MB of memory used by your 9000-object test is miniscule - are you expecting this to be a problem, or are you testing out of curiosity?

Comment: Curiosity and more, I have a memory grow problem in my other application, which seems to have properly implemented IDisposable interfaces, but simulating some big amount of work and leaving my app for few hours cause that the consumed memory is growing and growing (and never decreasing)

Comment: If the memory is growing indefinitely (and assuming that you are expecting it to be released), then you might have an issue that is causing your memory to not be released.

Comment: Your posted code that generates a tiny amount of memory use is not likely to release the memory.  An alternative application with heavier memory use might be very different.

Comment: IDispose provides nice method for closeing streams etc., but YOu application can still hold reference to object somewhere, so even if it's "disposed"(method Dispose() was called), it can still be in memory.

Comment: At the end of my program I am calling GC.Collect() to force the clean-up. But after that amount of used memory is not decreased. I am still confused.